# Pinching the ends of a layer

Tags: gimp, distort

I'm working in gimp. I want to put two letters on a chevron shaped shield. I want the letters to squish together at the ends and stay larger in the middle where they meet.

Here's where I am.
[image]

I've messed around with the distorts, but can't figure out how to do this. I thought this wouldn't be hard, but it is evading me.

Comment: Much better handled in vector editors.

Comment: @user287001 - Inkscape does have an envelope live path effect, also a lattice deform live path effect. But GIMP isn't the right kind of software for this. It's a photo editor, not for making logos.

Comment: @BillyKerr Those path effects seemed an obvious way to get this as easily as in Illustrator. But they were not (tried). Or deeper understanding and better practicing is needed. If you show this in Inkscape at least I will upvote it.

Comment: @user287001 - I would be happy to do that, but the OP would need to add an Inkscape tag or at least mention the possibility of using other software.  For what it's worth, [here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/4jJtsb5) of the Lattice Deformation LPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite complicated to be done properly. There is a script that can bend things accurately and works on paths, so there is no blur (which is a consequence of all other techniques).

**Warning**: this whole explanation require some familiarity with paths and the path tool. Official Gimp doc on the subject is [here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html) with some additional and useful reading [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Working-with-Paths) and [there](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Paths-Basics).

Redoing your image from scratch:

- Create a path which is one half of the shield
- Make a copy
- Mirror one of the instances and merge it with its source (this will be used to create the shield)
- Clip a bit of the ends of the second instance
- Mirror it and merge (this will be used to warp the text)
- Create the text, and obtain a path from it (`Layer > text to path`)
- Add a pair of guides, left and right, spaced from the text about as much as what you want you text to be space for the shield
- Since the script can only work vertically, we have to rotate the image temporarily (`Image > Transform > Rotate > 90° CCW`)

At that point you should have something like this:

[image]

- Right-click the text path (`KW`), and apply the `ofn-bend-path` (`Tools > Bend...`) using the `Reference lines: Guides` option.

You should have something like this with a new path added:

[image]

To finish up, rotate the image again, in the opposite direction  (`Image > Transform > Rotate > 90° CW`)

- Right click the bent text path, and `Fill path...`
- Right click the shield path, and `Stroke path...` Use `Line` mode with  a rather wide (blue) line
- Right click the shield path, and `Stroke path...` again, use `Line` mode with  a thinner white line.

Final result:

[image]

The two useful scripts are:

- `path-mirror` (doc [here](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml#path-mirror))
- `ofn-bend-path` (doc in HTML in ZIP).

and can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/). Some examples with `ofn-bend-path` can be found [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-ofn-bend-path).

One problem above is that the outer sides of the K and W aren't parallel, so the output looks a bit asymmetric, but this shouldn't happen for you since you use a font where the end of the `W` is nearly vertical.